# How to get image from external storage using shared preferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-image

In my application what I am doing is hat I am taking a button to start camera and take a pic and store it in external storage and save the path in SharePreferences and I want to access and display the image taken earlier in second activity but I am not getting how to get the image in second activity. Please help me?

MainActivity.java

```
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File f=getExternalFilesDir("Images");
File f1=new File(f,"Image"+count);
Uri parse=  Uri.fromFile(f1);
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,parse);
SharedPreferences sp= getSharedPreferences("ll",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor e= sp.edit();
e.putString("imagepath",f1.getAbsolutePath());
e.commit();
if (i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(i,1);
}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
SharedPreferences sp= getSharedPreferences("kl",MODE_PRIVATE);
String encoded=sp.getString("hj","No Image");
```

now how to get image from this string?

Edit 1:

Yesy that is fin and thanks. i just corrected the key in MainAtivity

here is the modified code:

MainActivity.java

```
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File f=getExternalFilesDir("Images");
File f1=new File(f,"Image"+count);
Uri parse=  Uri.fromFile(f1);
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,parse);
SharedPreferences sp= getSharedPreferences("ll",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor e= sp.edit();
e.putString("hj",f1.getAbsolutePath());
e.commit();
if (i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(i,1);
}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
SharedPreferences sp= getSharedPreferences("kl",MODE_PRIVATE);
String encoded=sp.getString("hj","No Image");
```

but still I have the path to image in external storage how to use it do display the image in activity?

Comment: You are setting the image using key **imagepath** and while retriving you are using **hj**. Isn't it looks wrong to you

Comment: you're also getting the wrong SharedPreference. Please use static finals for keys so that you have the same key when saving and retrieving.